# Сложение и вычитание вещественных чисел

Tags: javascript

Есть такая особенность,которая выводит не правильные результаты

```
alert(0.1+0.2);//0.30000000000000004
alert(0.7-0.2);//0.49999999999999994
```

Проблема со сложение решена так

```
function sum() {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0, max = arguments.length; i< max; i++ ) {
      result += arguments[i]*10;
    }
    return result / 10;
  }
```

Но как решить проблему с вычитанием правильно?

Comment: округлением попробуйте.

Comment: как вариант использовать готовую библиотеку, например, [эту](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/numbers.html) или [эту](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) (ни с одной из них не работал, нашел в гугле)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Представление плавающих значений допускает подобного вида погрешности и это нормально. Для того, что бы привести число в более подобающий вид, можно воспользоваться принудительным обрезанием мусора числа через [toFixed](http://javascript.ru/Number/toFixed) или [toPrecision](http://javascript.ru/Number/toPrecision).

```
function floatFixed(fValue){
    return parseFloat( fValue.toFixed(8) );
}
console.log(floatFixed(0.1 + 0.2));
console.log(floatFixed(0.7 - 0.2));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Документация](https://learn.javascript.ru/number#%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) некоторых функций для округления.

```
var n = 0.7-0.2; //0.49999999999999994
n.toFixed(2); //0.50
Math.round(n * 10) / 10; //0.5
```